# Express in symbols: "There is a real number that is not the cube of any real number besides itself."

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

> I have the following statement, and I want to use symbols only to express its meaning.
>
> > There is a real number that is not the cube of any real number besides itself.

Here is my answer (assuming that $x$ and $y$ are in the universal set $R$ just to make the notation shorter):

$$(\exists x)(\forall y)(x \neq y^3)$$

Is this correct?

Thank you ^^

Comment: You're missing "except itself".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close...but not quit. Assuming we all know from where $\;x,\,y\;$ come, we can simply write

$$\exists\,x\,\forall\,y\left((y\neq x\implies x\neq y^3)\;\wedge x^3=x\right)$$

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\exists x(x^3=x\land\forall y\ne x(x\ne y^3))$?

Comment: @KentaS True, forgot the $\;y\neq x$  part. Thanks., editing

Comment: I think this is wrong. Your translation requires that $x$ be a cube. But the original statement does not require this. It only requires that $x$ _not_ be a cube of any _other_ number.

Comment: Compare for example "there is a person who is not the mother of any person besides themself". This is true; for example in the case of Isaac Newton who is not the mother of anyone at all, which is a strict superset of the set of all people besides Newton.  But your translation would require an example be their own mother.

Comment: @MJD I don't understand your objection. There is written (with the set of real numbers in the background, of course): there exists a real number  (x) which for any real number (y), if $\;y\neq x\;$ then $\;x\;$ is not the the cube of $\;y\;$ , yet (or "and") $\;x\;$ is a cube of itself. The formula is well formed and the underlying statement is true, with $\;x=1\;$ , certainly...which of course is a cube.

Comment: @MJD Oh, and the OP did require $\;x\;$ to be a cube. That's the translation of "...besides itself"

Answer (score 1):

Since this seems like a nonsense statement, I would be clear to translate verbatim

$$
\exists x, \forall y \neq x:  x \neq y^3
$$

There is a real number:  $\exists x$

For any real number besides itself:  $\forall y \neq x$

Is not the cube of:  $x \neq y^3$

Answer (score 0):

I´rather use $$\exists x\in\mathbb{R}\quad \text{ s.t. }\quad x\not=y^3 \wedge x^3=x  \quad\forall y\not=x \in \mathbb{R}.$$ If you add $x$ and $y$ belongs in $\mathbb{R}$, your answer will look fine to me.

Comment: In mathematical logic (predicate calculus or first order logic) there exists a certain order in which quantifiers appear in a well-formed sentence. That last quantifier of yours seems to be out of place.

Comment: Thank you @DonAntonio for the comment, I didn't know that. But even if it is not 100% correct, placing the $\forall y \not= x\ldots$ at the end of the sentence looks clearer to me and easier to read. At the end of the day all the author wanted was to use 'symbols'.

Comment: There's an ambiguity when you put quantifiers at the end: does the universal quantifier encompass everything to the left, or only the part within the "there exists"?  There's no real established convention, which is why putting quantifiers at the end tends to be discouraged in mathematical writing (even when not written symbolically).  Putting parentheses around the universally quantified part, though, would disambiguate it in this case.